# Дописывать приставку к возрасту

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код, который считает возраст:

```
var today = new Date();
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var Name = question2[1].FIO + '(' + (yyyy - question2[1].Age)+')';
```

Но вот в чем задачка, нужно дописывать, лет, год и т.д

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Смотрим по **предпоследней** цифре: если 1 - лет иначе по **последней** цифре: 1 - год, 2-4 года, остальное - лет.

```js
var years = [ 1822,1922,1948,1990,1995,1996,2008,2014,2016 ]

years.forEach(function(year){
  let thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  let yearsOld = thisYear - year;
  document.write(yearsOld + " " + getYearAddition(yearsOld) + "<br>");
});

function getYearAddition(year) {
    let preLastDigit = Math.floor(year % 100 / 10);
    if (preLastDigit === 1) {
        return "лет";
    }

    let lastDigit = year % 10;
    switch (lastDigit) {
        case 1:
            return "год";
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return "года";
        default:
            return "лет";
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Решение с moment.js [Durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) и [i18n](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/)

```js
var years = [ 1822,1922,1948,1990,1995,1996,2008,2014,2016 ]
years.forEach(function(year){
  let yearsOld = moment().diff(moment([year]), 'year');
  let yearsOldHumanized = moment.duration(yearsOld, 'years').humanize();
  document.write(yearsOldHumanized + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/ru.js"></script>
```